# External monitor Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit not working

Tags: external-monitor

just installed Ubuntu 11.04, but cannot get my external monitor to work in "same image in all monitors" mode.

Its only possible to choose same resolution for the external monitor as for the laptop.

External is 1920*1080, laptop 1200*800px

When mirror is selected, ubuntu identifies BOTH monitors as "laptop" and BOTH monitored displays 1200*800px.

Any help much appreciated ...

Comment: Isn't that expected behavior? Can't really have same image on both if the image would be of higher resolution, than one of the monitors supports. On the other hand I'm using extend mode, and it works perfectly (1280x800 internal, 1920x1200 external)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a Nvidia graphic-card? There is a special tool for Nvidia called disper. It should work with other cards too.

You can install *disper* from *ppa:disper-dev/ppa*

Then type

```
disper -c
```

This should clone the desktops on internal an external monitor. See [here](https://launchpad.net/disper) on launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get monitors to work correctly in any distribution of Linux since Soft-landing. Every time a new distribution comes out and I try and get it, and even today the monitor handling is worse than Windows 95 was back then.

The closest I ever came was using `xrandr` in 10.04, so that's my answer and suggestion - just read as much as you can find about `xrandr`.

If I recall correctly, I was able to rotate a display, but then the other monitors

I suggest just being happy with just the one monitor.